# For what values of $x ∈ R$ will the real part of all eigenvalues for the system be negative?

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

This is a system of differential equations with the form:

$$ x'(t)=A*x(t) $$

I have the following matrix:

$$\left(
        \begin{matrix}
        -1 & x & 2 \\
        4 & -1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & -3 \\
        \end{matrix}
\right)$$

The parameter x is a real constant where $$ x ≠ 0 $$
To solve this problem, I tried solving the characteristic polynomium:

$$ |A-\lambda*E|=0 $$

Where I ended up with:

$$ -(\lambda+3)*(\lambda^2+2*\lambda+1-4*x) $$

The first root is -3, which satisfies the initial condition. To find the remaining roots, I solved the latter equation:

$$ \lambda=\frac{-2±\sqrt {2^2-4*1*(1-4x)}}{2*1} $$

Which gives me:

$$ \lambda=-1+2\sqrt x $$ and $$ \lambda=-1-2\sqrt x $$

To find which values of x would meet the above condition, I solve the inequality lambda < 0 for the first one:

$$ -1+2\sqrt(x)<0 \implies \frac {1}{4} > x $$

I'm relatively sure this is the answer, but I'm not sure what to do with the second equation. I can't find any other solutions to this. I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Don't forget complex numbers. If the square root yields an imaginary number, then the real part will also be negative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x<0$, $\sqrt{x}$ is imaginary, so the real part of $-1-2\sqrt{x}$ is $-1<0$. If $x\geq 0$, then $-1-2\sqrt{x}\leq -1<0$. So every $x$ makes the real part of the eigenvalue $-1-2\sqrt{x}$ negative.

Comment: My bad. See the comment below.

Comment: I am referring to just the eigenvalue $-1-2\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: So essentially, the parameter x doesn't play a role for the second eigenvalue. The parameter can be any real number apart from 1/4. Is that right?

Comment: If $x=1/4$, then $-1-2\sqrt{x}=-2<0$, so this is okay for the second eigenvalue. If you want all three eigenvalues to have negative real part, then you must have $x<1/4$.

Comment: I see, but I'm still unsure about one thing. The confusing part is that when I type in any other real number for x in the matrix and go through the process again, all three of the eigenvalues' real parts are negative, apart from 1/4. How does that make sense with $$ x < 1/4 $$?

Comment: When I put in $x=0$, I get one eigenvalue with a value $1$.

Comment: As I edited later in my OP, the parameter x can't equal 0.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $x=1$.

Comment: Makes sense then. The system will remain asymptotic stable as long as x < 1/4, right? If you only look at the real part of the eigenvalues

Comment: Rather, stability only depends on the real part, but yes.